# How to not slide off the stairs in game mode?

Tags: game-engine, physics, logic-bricks

**How I can stop in the middle of the stairs without sliding off ?**
With the current setup the collision mesh which my camera is parent to slides
down the created stair ramp object whenever I stop halfway up the stairs.

[image]

sorry, I find it difficult to explain in English because I use g.translate, I hope there who understand the intent of the question in my image.
thank you

Comment: Friction in the material physics panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest you switch it around. Instead of adding a mesh along the stair's geometry you could just make your character's collision mesh with a chamfer. In that way you don't have to create extra meshes for your stairway.

Without the ramp object the mesh will not slide down a gradient but rest on the surface of perfectly flat geometry in your scene when you stop.

[image]